# IE7 abnormally expands table cells with buttons

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been reading about this bug in IE7 which makes padding increase in buttons according to the amount of text that they have. I finally solved this by adding `overflow: visible` to the button class, but it seems that, although the buttons are displayed with the correct width, this bug still affects the elements surrounding the buttons. In this case, when the buttons are inside a table cell, the cell becomes much larger than it should be.

The effect can be seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YTqN/1/). The gap between buttons is much smaller in modern browsers and abnormally wide in IE7. I'm looking for a way to eliminate this gap, thanks.

**EDIT**: Well I'll be using Diodeus' suggestion, but it would still be interesting to know if there's a fix for this.

Comment: Use display:block and style an anchor tag to look like your button. Problem solved.

Comment: such a shame to have to put in so much effort to support a browser that has so few users. Is this for a corporate intranet or something?

Comment: @Diodeus Ha! Now why didn't I think of that.

Comment: @Spudley yes, unfortunately this is a corporate intranet thing. I said "let's go 9 and up" and they gave me a funny look.

Comment: Sad really. I can understand using IE8 still, but IE7 is just nuts. With IE6 there were apps that required it that prevented the upgrade, but with IE7 there's virtually zero barriers to upgrading to IE8 apart from corporate inertia.